# How to restrict people forwarding or saving content received from a Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I recently communicated with a bot that had this feature - I could not save photos nor videos that he sent me.

But when I create my own bot, I struggle to find such a setting.

Please advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `protect_content` option of `sendMessage` (or `sendPhoto`/`sendVideo` etc.). For example, this should send you a text message that cannot be forwarded: [https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/sendMessage?chat_id=[id]&text=Not%20forwardable&protect_content=true](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5Btoken%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=%5Bid%5D&text=Not%20forwardable&protect_content=true)

(Remember to replace `[token]` with your bot token as well as `[id]` with your chat ID)